# How can I see the IP of whom accessed a system using CM Remote Control?

Tags: registry, remote-access, sccm, event-viewer

I was trying to check on the IP address of a mysterious remote session.
We are phasing out SCCM/MECM, and currently are unable to run reports and audit remote sessions.

I have checked Event Viewer in Applications and Service Logs > Microsoft > Windows > TerminalServices - LocalSessionManager and RemoteSessionManager. I found no events.

I have run filters to try and find event IDs 1146/47/48.

I have gone into the registry to look for remote sessions.

I have even attempted to test during an active remote session into my own system in CMD using:
netstat -n | find: "3389" and nothing comes up.

Any solution to this would be appreciated, and win my respect and admiration!

Answer (score 0):

In the console you should be able to go to Monitoring --> Status Message Queries and there is one "Remote Control Activity Targeted at a Specific System" that should contain the host from which the connection was initiated. Alternatively you can also check logs for all remote control sessions on the whole site using a similar query.

These messages are only logged if the CmRcViewer.exe is started with the site server as parameter but in all standard environments this would normally be the case.